# insert XML into DOM leads to not working class/id selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, dom

I'm trying to load an XML file with ajax and insert parts of this XML DOM document into the browsers HTML DOM.

This works so far, but when I try to get an inserted element with a class or id selector with jquery it returns the empty list.

I tried it only in firefox 10 so far. does anyone have a clue why this might be? is it just not safe to do so?

test.html:

```
<html><head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>dom test</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      var xml = null;
      $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        url : 'test.xml',
        dataType : "xml",
        success : function(data) {
          xml = data;
        }
      });

      $('body').html($(xml).children().clone());

      console.log($('h1')); // prints the h1 element
      console.log($('.title')); // prints empty list

      console.log($('p')); // prints the p element
      console.log($('#content')); // prints empty list
    });      
  </script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

test.xml:

```
<div id="root">
  <h1 class="title">Blabla</h1>
  <p id="content">
    Lorem ipsum
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: what does the body of the page look like after running this?

Comment: Try changing the `dataType` to `'html'`...also, why are you using `.clone()`?

Comment: @daniel, the source looks like expected, the code from the xml properly inserted.

Comment: @chris, datatype to html is not enough, then the document must be real html. clone() is not needed for the test case, it doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you are just trying to grab HTML via AJAX and then insert it into your page. To do that you should be using `dataType: "html"` in your ajax request.

```
$(function() {
    var html = null;
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        async : false,
        url : 'test.xml',
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data) {
            html = data;
        }
    });

    $('body').html(html);

});
```

Comment: This is just a simple testcase, the real XML has only some parts which needs to be inserted and look like HTML. Setting data type to 'html' is also not enough. i have to add a html root element with a proper xmlns declaration.

Answer (score -1):

It is doing as expected. Can verify by alerting the `$(xnl).find("h1").text()`. however can you please try with changing double quotes to single quotes in your xml. and disabling HTML5 support in your ff (that might be the issue too)?